# Ionic framework error: spawn unknown error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, serve

When I try to run this command:ionic serve, then I got the following error in the terminal.

```
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at spawn
(C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:173:12)
at Subprocess.spawn
(C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:146:16)
at Shell.spawn (C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\shell.js:151:24)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawn (C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:345:19)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawnWrapper (C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:321:20)
at async AngularServeCLI.serve (C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:311:9)
at async AngularServeRunner.serveProject
(C:\Users\Ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\angular\serve.js:117:9)
```

Please find below versions for the libraries used.

**Ionic:**

1. Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1
2. Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.3.1
3. @angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.2.0
4. @angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.2.0
5. @angular/cli                  : 16.2.0
6. ionic/angular-toolkit         : 9.0.0

**Capacitor:**

1. Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.3
2. @capacitor/android : 5.3.0
3. @capacitor/core    : 5.3.0
4. @capacitor/ios     : 5.3.0

**Utility:**

1. cordova-res : not installed globally
2. native-run  : 1.7.2

**System**

1. NodeJS : v18.16.0
2. npm    : 9.5.1
3. OS     : Windows 10

Comment: some people said that error is caused by antivirus , you can try it

Answer (score 0):

After disabling the virus guard it worked for me

Thank you

Comment: Please mark this answer as the solution so everyone can see it.